# Migrating from kotlin-android-extensions to newer view binding

Tags: kotlin, view, android-viewbinding

So if you are getting anything like below

```
> Configure project :app
Warning: The 'kotlin-android-extensions' Gradle plugin is deprecated.
```

This probably means which means that using Kotlin synthetics for view binding is no longer supported / deprecated.

So below is the answer where you can clearly get understanding on how to get / identify your ViewBinding class related to your views.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

In order to migrate to the newer way of binding you need to first remove the kotlin synthetics plugin which could have been added as below :

```
apply plugin: 'kotlin-android-extensions'
```

OR

```
plugins {
    ...
    id 'kotlin-android-extensions'
}
```

after removing synthetic plugin from app gradle you need to remove the imports which could like either of below :

- activity /fragment view : import
  kotlinx.android.synthetic.main.<your_activity_view>.*
- normal views :
  import kotlinx.android.synthetic.main.<your_layout_view>.view.*

Now begins actual migration

You need to add below inside your app gradle

```
android {
     ... 
     buildFeatures {
        viewBinding true
    }
}
```

After this you need to add a binding property where your view is to be bound.
Below is an example
:

```
private lateinit var binding: ActivityMainBinding

override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
    binding = ActivityMainBinding.inflate(layoutInflater)
    val view = binding.root
    setContentView(view)

    binding.myTextView.text = "my text" //say your text view id is like : my_text_view"
}
```

Note : if your activity layout is activity_main.xml then your binding should be ActivityMainBinding

[here](https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/view-binding#fragments) you will find view binding example for fragment

[here](https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/view-binding/migration) is official migration doc from google