# Replacing data binding from kotlin-android-extensions to kotlin-kapt

Tags: android, kotlin, data-binding, android-viewbinding

As kotlin-android-extensions is deprecicated in kotlin 4.20 I wanted to move code to supported method. I tried https://medium.com/back-market-engineering/from-kotlin-synthetics-to-android-viewbinding-the-definitive-guide-c98c6e89fe0b still data binding is not really well described.

Comment: You're conflating data binding with view binding (two different things) and you don't need to work with kotlin-kapt to use view binding.

Comment: Possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65009040/migrating-from-kotlin-android-extensions-to-newer-view-binding

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure if data binding is really needed. Anyway if code works before and we want to make it work without kotlin-android-extensions  we have to do:
Replace in gradle file code `apply plugin 'kotlin-android-extensions' to plugins{  id 'kotlin-android'  id 'kotlin-kapt'}`
In class that uses `import kotlinx.android.synthetic.` to

```
private var _binding: YourLayoutNameBinding? = null //YourLayoutName change to your Layout name
private val binding get() = _binding!!
override fun onCreateView(
    inflater: LayoutInflater,
    container: ViewGroup?,
    savedInstanceState: Bundle?
): View {
    _binding = YourLayoutNameBinding.inflate(inflater, container, false)//YourLayoutName change to your Layout name
    return binding.root
}


override fun onDestroyView() {
    super.onDestroyView()
    _binding = null
}
```